# display only cells with value in Pop Up Form

Tags: excel, vba

the macro below takes two cell values (from first and second column)
and displays the column and there cell content in a Pop up Form

Im trying to add the condition that only the column and cell value is displayed if the cell contains value.

something like that `=IF(A1<>"",result,"")`

but I dont know how to implement that for all cells not only for a specific one.

```
Option Explicit

Const rangeForSearch = "G2"

Const rowTitles = 4

Dim arrTmp
Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Long
Dim textForSearch As String, textForSearch_withoutSpaces As String
Dim strTmp As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Sub searchPerson()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        textForSearch = .Range(rangeForSearch)
        If textForSearch = "" Then
            MsgBox "Input text in cell """ & rangeForSearch & """ and try again!", vbCritical
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastColumn = .Cells(rowTitles, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lastRow <= rowTitles Or lastColumn <= 2 Then
            MsgBox "Dataset is wrong! Check it and try again!", vbCritical
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        arrTmp = .Range(.Cells(rowTitles, "A"), .Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    End With
    '---------------------------------------
    textForSearch_withoutSpaces = Replace(textForSearch, " ", "")
    
    For i = LBound(arrTmp, 1) + 1 To UBound(arrTmp, 1)
        strTmp = Replace(arrTmp(i, 1) & arrTmp(i, 2), " ", "")
        If StrComp(textForSearch_withoutSpaces, strTmp, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit For
    Next i
    If i = UBound(arrTmp, 1) + 1 Then
            strTmp = textForSearch & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "No dataset!"
        Else
            strTmp = textForSearch
            For j = 3 To lastColumn
                strTmp = strTmp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & arrTmp(1, j) & ": " & arrTmp(i, j)
            Next j
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox strTmp, , "Result"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe

```
        For j = 3 To lastColumn
            If Not IsEmpty(arrTmp(i, j)) Then strTmp = strTmp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & arrTmp(1, j) & ": " & arrTmp(i, j)
        Next j
```

Comment: its not clear at which part of the code to insert your condition , inserting it after the `textForSearch` part at the top gives me a `runtime error, Index out of range`

Comment: it's to substitute the very same `For j = 3 To lastColumn` ... `Next j` from your original code